# Irreducible Representations of Quaternions over $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

This is a follow up question to this:

[Representation of quaternion group over $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23324/representation-of-quaternion-group-over-mathbbc-and-mathbbr)

I am trying to prove the Quaternions group does not have an irreducible 2-dimensional representation over the real numbers.

I understand the general idea of the Algebraic answer given, however I want to understand better how one can show that there is always a basis for which $i$ acts according to that matrix.

I can see why this is true if we know that such a 2-dimensional representation must act on the plane by reflections and rotations, but why is this the case? Do we use the fact that the 2-dimensional representation is irreducible in this argument?

How should one think about this geometrically? The answer seems to hint that any group representation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be thought of as reflections and rotations of the plane. How would that fit in with, say, taking the direct sum of two 1-dimensional irreducible representations?

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The quaternion group has no $2$-dimensional irreducible representation over $\Bbb Q$. This is easy to see by an elementary calculation with matrices. This computation is (perhaps) better than arguing with rotations and reflections.
It is an independent argument for $\Bbb Q$, and hence for $\Bbb R$.  As a consequence the quaternion group also does not have a $2$-dimensional irreducible representation over $\Bbb R$. It is also easy to show that $Q_8$ cannot be realized as a subgroup of $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$ over the integers. This can be seen by passing to $\Bbb Z/2$ and deriving a contradiction.

The fact that "there is always a basis for which $i$ acts according to that matrix" follows from the relations in the quaternion group, see here:

[The order of the Quaternion Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/360122/the-order-of-the-quaternion-group)